# AWS - Terraform - SCP - MalformedPolicyDocumentException

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, jsonencoder

```
resource "aws_organizations_policy" "tag_enforcement_eks" {
  name = "tag_enforcement_eks"
  content = <<EOT
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Deny if org:bu absent",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "eks:CreateNodegroup",
                "eks:CreateCluster"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/org:bu": ${jsonencode(var.bu)}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Deny if org:zone absent",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "eks:CreateNodegroup",
                "eks:CreateCluster"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/org:zone": ${jsonencode(var.zone)}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Deny if org:team absent",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "eks:CreateNodegroup",
                "eks:CreateCluster"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/org:team": ${jsonencode(var.team)}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Deny if org:cluster absent",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "eks:CreateNodegroup",
                "eks:CreateCluster"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/org:cluster": ${jsonencode(var.cluster)}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
  EOT
}
```

MalformedPolicyDocumentException: The provided policy document does not meet the requirements of the specified policy type.
Creating a Service Control Policy, I see the code to be correct, cant verify where is the problem. Can anyone help me out?

Where is the error?

Comment: How do you know the code is correct? What are your variables?

Comment: variables are a list of strings. I know that the code is correct as I have reproduced it on VisualEditor on the SCP Console, and its working there.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this line:

```
"Sid": "Deny if org:bu absent"
```

JSON Spaces, `-`, `_`, `:`, and probably a few other characters aren't allowed.

> The Sid element supports ASCII uppercase letters (A-Z), lowercase letters (a-z), and numbers (0-9).